# How do I make some random numbers appear more than others?

Tags: php, random, ads

I am trying to host my own advertising.  For example, I want those that bid up to $0.25 PPC to show more impressions than those that bid up to $0.10.  I want to put my numbers in a random array with the higher bidders showing more impressions.  I think I'm looking at the wrong logic.  I could maybe figure out the correct way of doing this myself if my logic can be pointed in the correct direction.

Comment: Share what you have tried

Comment: If customer 5 pays for 1 ad, you put 5 in the array once. If customer 10 pays for twice as many impressions, you put 10 in the array twice. If someone pays for three times the impressions, you put them in the array three times. The more you put a customer in the array, the more it will show.

Comment: So... what if I was to use `rand` for this?  Is putting the same number twice a legal operation?  `rand(5,10,10)`

Comment: This might work, I can assign one point to every cent. $0.01 = 1 occurrence and $0.10 = 10 occurrences.  I think I understand this logic and will give it a shot.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zarthus's last suggestion is the right way to do this:

```
    class AdObject
    {
        private $asset = 0;

        function __construct($asset)
        {
            $this->asset = $asset;
        }

        public function getAsset()
        {
            return $this->asset;
        }

        public function setAsset($asset_input)
        {
            $this->asset = $asset_input;
        }

        public function getScore()
        {
            return ($this->asset *(float)rand()/(float)getrandmax());
        }
    }

    function chooseAdvertising($ads_array)
    {
        $scores_array = array ();

        foreach ($ads_array as $value)
            $scores_array[] = $value->getScore();

        $max_indexes = array_keys($scores_array, max($scores_array));
        return $max_indexes[0];
    }
    $advertisment_arr = array (new AdObject("0.15"), new AdObject("0.20"), new AdObject("0.32"));
```

We will assume that the chooseAdvertising function will give you the index of the ad you want to display which are contained in $advertisment_arr.

You can customize the function getScore or the attributes of AdObject to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add them more times in an array (which is a solution; but quite possibly not the best way to go about this).

Let's imagine each we have a weight. For each ten cents given we duplicate the element to the array.

For my example, we have `company1` which gave $0.30, and `company2` which gave $0.10.

Your array would look like this:

```
$data = array(
  'company1', 'company1', 'company1',
  'company2'
);
```

However, the issue with this type of generation is that your arrays may become quite big. For larger applications, this may not be ideal.

As far as the most efficient solution, I think you're asking the wrong question--you should look at making your own algorithm that shows people who paid more to show up more frequently, and not base it off of random number generation.

Comment: Thank You very much.  I think I understand what logic to use and will give it a shot. :)

Comment: Assuming this was a larger application, what documentation can I read to develop a better way to do this?  Although I'm not big now, I hope to be in the very near future and would prefer to use a solution for larger applications from the start.  I don't need a long drawn out answer if you don't want.  Just need to know where to look for the solution.  Thank You.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the best approach would be, I would certainly try to find out how bigger advertisement companies do it like Google's Ad Service.  Something along the lines of counting how often something has been shown to the user in the database would definitely help, and basing which ad to show off of which has less shows and much higher paid than the other records.

Answer (score 0):

my ideas would be:

1) work with an threshold of uses and determin its max size based on the ads payment. f.e. set the amout of uses to the amount of cent paid. After all thresholds are empty reset them all. Afaik that's simular to how google works for their ad-system.

2) Work with a secon rand. let that compare to a vaktor for ech ad, f.e. the cents paid for it. Only if that second rand is bigger than the faktor you use it. otherwise you repeat the first rand to get a new ad.

in terms of buissness the first one should be the way to go. You could even combine both. The threshold from 1) could be the factor for the second rand in 2).

Comment: Thank You very much everyone.  I think these solutions will work. :)